# Listview control image display

Tags: listview, controls

I currently used a gridview and im able to populate something similar to this where the project titles are links to another page called "projects"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IROe4.jpg

what i want is to be able to click on the option in the top right and get this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuoNh.jpg

where images based on my projectid are listed..and those pictures will be links to the projects page as well

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So you want to be able to switch from a 'grid-type-view' to 'tile-type-view'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rough psuedo-code you could do it a couple of ways.

1) Have 2 listviews - one displaying in grid format, one in tiled and based on which button was hit display and bind data to the relevant listview.

2) Have one listview and in its itemdatabound method alter/show-hide different elements in the ItemTemplate/Alternating ItemTemplate based on which button was hit. You would also need to change i.e. a CSS wrapping element so that your css effected the change in layout

Comment: #2 would be a bit of a stretch for you I think (you asking this question indicates limited knowledge of ASP.NET and you would have a lot of fun navigating control hierarchies, using some of the more advanced event handlers, not to mention possible swithcing of datasource... but both are possible ways.

Comment: #1 is cleaner imho - though watch out for databinding both listviews (2 hits instead of one - databind only one programatically (not use datasource declarative syntax)

Comment: actually wouldnt let me add it. but are you saying that these two instances would have to exist in the same control to have the best outcome..for example having the user click the tile view option and the listview with images become available?

Comment: Also do you know any samples of a tiled listview..you were right when saying my knowledge was limited. Appreciate the responses tho!

Comment: You need to use ItemTemplate and GroupTemplate. This allows you to create the tiled view (i.e. add a wrapper dive around every 'n' ItemTemplate

Comment: yes you can have many ListViews on one page ... and they can all look at the same data. You would just toggle Visible=True/False and set lvGrid.DataSource = List; lvGrid.DataBind(); lvGrid.Visible = true; lvTiles.Visible = false; and switcharoo the code round if the other display button was chosen.

Comment: yes i currently use the item template in the gridview (first image) in order to display then action links on the right..the others are boundfields <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectStatus" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="ProjectStatus" />  etc  i guess i will have to move all this to a listview instead unless i cant combine them?

Comment: You can just stick with your old gridview for the grid and use listview for the tiled but I strongly recommend you start using ListView for everything - it is a repeater, gridview, detailview (it can basically do everything).

Comment: Appreciate the help! is there not any built in controls for the "tiled" option in listview is there? i did some quick google searchin but couldnt find anything. Looks like im in for a few hours or work

Comment: There is a default template available for 'FlowLayout' but just read up on ListView.GroupTemplate - have a play and then just combine some CSS with it to do the tiling